# extjs-adding a record to a store does not reflect on the grid

Tags: extjs

hi i have grid with store and i add record dynamically to the store for most times the data being added to the store gets reflected on the grid but sometimes the record dont seem to get reflected on the grid..please help me solve this problem

```
var entityGrid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({

    ddGroup           : 'gridDDGroup',
    layout            : 'fit',
    store             : gridStore,
    closable          : true,
    enableDragDrop    : true,
    enableColumnMove  : false,
    enableColumnResize: true,
    columnLines       : true,
    stripeRows        : true,
    colModel          : new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
        columns:cols
    }),
    expandable        : true,
    autoExpandColumn  : 'name',
    tbar              : gridToolBar,
    view              : new Ext.grid.GridView({  
        enableRowBody : true,
        ignoreAdd     : true,       
        deferEmptyText: false,
        emptyText     : 'No Record found.',       
        getRowClass   : function(record, rowIndex, rp, ds){}
    }), 
    id                : id,
    selModel          : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        singleSelect  : true
    })

var store =new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields : [
        {
            name : 'name',
            mapping : 'name'
        }, {
            name : 'displayName',
            mapping : 'displayName'
        }
    ],
    root : masterData.
})
```

Comment: Can you post the code that adds records to the store?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it makes a difference but this code always worked for me:

```
var r = new store.recordType({ field1: '1', field2: '2' }); 
r.commit();
store.add(r);
store.commitChanges();
grid.store.sort('field1', 'ASC');
```

Try adding commitChanges() and refreshing.

Comment: var gridRecord = entityGrid getStore().recordType; var data = new gridRecord({ name:name,displayName :displayName }) entityGrid.insert(0,data);

Comment: `recordType` is gone in ExtJS 4+

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're still plagued by this problem, but I found the code at:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141982-commitChanges-and-rejectChanges-for-the-Store-in-ExtJS-4

to be very useful as things changed moving to EXTJS-4.   Which version of EXTJS are you using?  Since you're using an EditorGridPanel, I'm guessing it's ExtJS 3.  If you'd like, I can contribute a code fragment that uses the above architecture successfully to update a record on a grid.